# Don't re-render math when editing tags

Tags: bug, mathjax, editor

For some reason, typing in the tag box causes the mathematics in the preview to be rerendered. This causes the textbox to jump around madly, making it impossible to click on a tag.

Please fix this; mathematics should only rerender when the text is being edited.

Comment: I'm struggling to repro; when I do it, the preview (with some complex tex I borrowed from other questions) holds solid. Any particular browser / OS? Is this when asking a question? Editing? Editing tags using the inline editor? or...? As a minor note: I wonder if this related to the fact that on some sites the tags can change the appearance (code language tags might affect how code is colorized, for example); but without a repro, it is hard to check

Comment: @MarcGravell Happens to me when editing (not inline) on a fairly weak machine. The effect is present on a stronger machine as well, but not as disruptive because it's over sooner. We don't have any tag-related formatting here. Current FF on GNU/Linux.

Comment: @MarcGravell The fast preview aggreviates the issue: line heights change twice in passes from top to bottom.